# angularjs to store basic profile data which can be shred to all controllers and apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am working on web application. once user log in i need to load user profile data somewhere which will be available to all controllers also to other application by adding dependency or something .

**i was thinking of writing ng-init() method and then storing all values in factory but is there any other way to achieve this i would just like to confirm.**

Please suggest what can i use to store user basic profile data ? is there any way to store in **config or provider** ?

```
drawerApp.config([ '$interpolateProvider',
    function ($interpolateProvider) {

 }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to store it in `localStorage` of the browser as a Object

to set

```
 var setUserData = {name:"abc",age:25}
 localStorageService.set('userData',JSON.stringify(setUserData));
```

to get `$scope.userData = JSON.parse(localStorageService.get('userData'));`

Comment: I agree. Remember localStorage capacity is usually 5MB at most (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values), but it should generally suffice for user profile data...

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha then on logout i will have to remove all this data from localStorage? is it safe ?

Comment: if ur going to save sensitive data definitely not its not safe, storing sensitive data in javascript / scope variables are also not safe. u have to find another way of saving sensitive data.
if ur need to destroy the data when logout `localStorage.clear()` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use root scope.Root scope is shared among all controllers and all html templates.so just store your user profile data in root scope.

Comment: no i cant use use i have different app also ... which i bootstrap with angular.bootstrap

Comment: then you have only option localStorage,just write localStorage["key"] = value